# Override exec systemcall with absolute path

Tags: linux, security, exec, system-calls

This is homework for systems security.

The assignment has 2 parts. 2 executables are given. *exectest* and *exectestsecure*.

After decompiling, I find the following:

**exectest**

```
...
execv("ls",...);
...
```

**exectestsecure**

```
...
execv("/bin/ls",...);
...
```

The goal is to print **Hello, World!** instead of running the ls command.

For the first part, I created the helloworld program and compiled it as *ls*, in my home directory. I then added my home directory to the PATH.

I don't understand what I can do for the *exectestsecure*, which uses an absolute path.

There are bonus points for running exectestsecure as root. The bonus uses an executable with setuid(0), and has the correct permissions. I think that if I find a way to hijack the call to /bin/ls, I can also answer the bonus question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override execv() with LD_PRELOAD, if libc is linked dynamically. Some tools that you will need: objdump, dlsym, strace. Find the path to follow [here](http://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/) for example.

Comment: I have tried to hijack the call to execv() using this method (it was taught in class). For some reason when running the executable is runs the system version of execv(). Am I doing something wrong? EDIT: I am not the owner of *exectestsecure*, it has setuid as root, maybe this is why?

Comment: I'd start checking that libc is actually linked dynamically. Then have you excluded this path? if yes, why? That's are the questions that you must answer to you yourself. "It doesn't work" is not enough to close this line... you need to understand "the reason" why it doesn't work and go on - that's your homework for :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked, and yes it is linked dynamically. Would the fact that *exectestsecure* elevates privileges "reset" any libraries I have dynamically loaded?

Comment: in case the executable is not suid-root it should (must!) work. For bonus points, it's not as immediate as you thought because libc resets *some* environment variables when running suid-root executables, LD_PRELOAD being one of them... it would be a really huge security hole, dont you think so? I think you need to investigate your binary and see for example if it is exploitable with some buffer overflow, or other weaknesses in the test itself. good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it does reset LD_PRELOAD, as I saw. The excersize specifically stated "Assume that no buffer overflow is possible" (even if it is). My main path was to alter the absolute path used by execv in memory, but memory protection doesn't allow it. Since I can't use chroot, I am afraid there is no other way (I know, at least).